# How to use XmlPeek task?

Tags: xml, msbuild, xml-parsing

I've read in the MSDN MSBuild Task Reference about XmlPeek task at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff598684(v=VS.100).aspx
but I cannot use it in my MSBuild script. If you have used this before, please show me how!

Comment: Can you post a segment of you MSBULD File please. I don't have it in ours anymore.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The XmlPeek task is only available in MSBuild for **.NET 4**. So you need to use MSBuild v4.0 and specify in your msbuild file the **tool version** you are using.

Here a sample project file, where we are looking for the message node.

```
  <Target Name="TestXmlPeek">
    <XmlPeek Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='msb' Uri='http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'/&gt;"
             XmlInputPath="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" 
             Query="/msb:Project/msb:Target[@Name='TestXmlPeek']/msb:Message">
      <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="Peeked" />
    </XmlPeek>

    <Message Text="@(Peeked)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks madgnome! It works now after I put ToolVersion=4.0 in the Project tag. The weird thing is that I'm running MSBuild Engine version 4.0.30319.1 as default but this "higher" version doesn't support XmlPeek!